# ggplot2: Combining two (or more) qqplots into one?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe "mockdat" with column "dat" being a univariate dataset of n=35 and a column "out" flagging a point either as outlier with the respective p-value or "NA".

I would like to create **one** qqplot with a common x-Axis, i.e. the theoretical quantiles of the whole n=35 but `stat_qq_line` and `stat_qqband()` calculated and colored separately for the levels defined by of "out"

Here is my attempt:

```
set.seed(42)
#
dat<-c(rnorm(n=30, mean=10, sd = 1),c(13.1, 14.2, 15.3, 12.9, 13.8))
out<-c(rep(NA,30),rep(99,5))
mockdat<-data.frame(dat,out=as.factor(out))
#

library(qqplotr)
ggplot(data = mockdat, aes(sample = dat, color=out)) +
  stat_qq_band() +
  stat_qq_line() +
  stat_qq_point()
```

What I get is shown below - wrong about it is the x-Axis which does not reflect the theoretical quantiles of dat.

Any ideas?

[image: wrong qqplot]

Comment: Is your question regarding the grouping for `color` or regarding how-to create a qqplot in general?

Comment: I think I know how to create a qqplot, What I would like to know is how to do grouping within one plot for confidence bands and line but keep one common x axis with the correct quantiles. You see in my graph that the quantiles ranging from 8-15 make no sense.

Comment: @HvL did you try to use base `ggplot2` functions? i.e. `ggplot2::stat_qq_line()`

Comment: But the scale of the x axis has nothing to do with the grouping. Try your code example without the color arg. The x axis is still not showing quantiles...

Comment: @atsynplenkov I would like to have confidence bands as displayed in my example. If you can "repair" the x-Axis with base ggplot2 functions and keep the grouping, CI etc then please post code.

Comment: @dario thanks, can you share code where the grouping, coloring and confidence intervals are retained **and** the x-Axis shows the quantiles of dat?

Comment: No, you should provide a qqplot as you want it, and then we can help you with the color-grouping problem. Otherwise please open a new question "how to create a qqplot" (But you already stated that you know that...)